# "It was not my intention."

Tags: grammar

How do I say the above sentence in Japanese? I would suppose it's

それは私の意向はなくなかったら。
(sore wa watashi no ikou wa nakunakatta.)

But I'm not sure about the 'nakunakatta'. It might be a double-negation?

Or might there even be a completely different sentence for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How we say it **totally** depends on the situation, the speaker, etc.

More common phrases would include:

「そういうつもりではありませんでした。」

「そんなつもりではなかったのです（or なかったんです）。」

「（それは）私の[本意]{ほんい}ではありません（or ありませんでした）。」

「（それは）私の[意図]{いと}していることではありません。」

The first two without using a Sino loanword would be the most versatile.  In formal or serious situations, however, the ones using a Sino loanword would sound better.

「本意」= one's real intention

「意図」= an intention

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples! One of those many Japanese sentences that require completely different thinking!